# How to clear select option in jQuery after submit

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I have a simple form which sends data to `process.php`.

My problem is how do I clear the select option after submitting the form?

I have a jQuery script that clears the select and brings back its default value but the problem is the default value is the one being passed in my `process.php` file instead of the selected value.

**Here is my jQuery code and my form:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('#custom-submit-input').click(function(){
              jQuery('#form-option').prop('selectedIndex',0);
            });

});
```

```php
echo "<form action='file-here/process.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' id='form-reset'>";
    echo "<iframe id='upload_target' name='upload_target' ></iframe>";
    echo "<select name='id' id='form-option' class='test-only'>";
    echo '<option selected="selected">' .'Choose a User'. '</option>';

    foreach ($registeredUsers as $key => $value) {
      $registered = JFactory::getUser($value);
      echo '<option value="'.$registered->id.'">'.$registered->name.'</option>';

    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<input name='uploadedfile' type='file' id='custom-file-input' class='test-only' /><br/>";
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="custom-submit-input"  >';
    echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Stack Snippets (the `<>` button) are for *live demos* in JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. For just code examples that aren't runnable, use the Code button (`{}`).

Comment: I've just had a look again at this because of popnoodles comment - and realised you want to clear the select after the form is submitted.  Are you submitting the form using ajax or do you just redirect to process.php?

Comment: Hi @Pete. Yes i just redirect the data to process.php. That is why going back to my question my jquery function clears the the select before it is submitted. That is why i am receiving the Choose a User in my database instead of the chosen select field.  Sorry for the long post.

Comment: If you are redirecting to another page, then why do you need to reset the value?  As you leave the current page, the user will not see the dropdown after the form is submitted so there is no need for the reset (which is probably what is causing your value to be wrong in the db)

Comment: So that it would look like an ajax where the page refresh is not needed for the select field to go back to its default value. I know i should use an ajax but it would take me some time and will change all of my code.

Comment: sorry, as you hadn't put the @Pete, it never showed me you added another comment.  I would just remove the `jQuery('#form-option').prop('selectedIndex',0);` line above from your code and then it should sumbit your data correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can use either

```
jQuery('#form-option').val('');  // sets the value of the select to the first option with a value of ''
```

Or

```
jQuery('#form-option').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;   // sets the value of the select back to the first option
```

Comment: I also trigger change `jQuery('#form-option').val('').trigger('change');` in case the form/element has other events bound to it, waiting for change.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **.reset()** function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('#custom-submit-input').click(function(){
              jQuery('#form-option').reset();
            });

});
```