# Modify filter function for select options in jQuery

Tags: jquery, filter

can someone help me with this filter function?
Let's say I have two select lists

```
<select id="select-item" class="input-items">
<option value="item1" data-category="new">Item 1</option>
<option value="item2" data-category="old">Item 2</option>
  
</select>

<select id="select-secondItem" class="input-items">
<option value="item2" data-category="old">Item 2</option> 
<option value="item3" data-category="new">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

Function filters great when comparing option values against each other, but I want to compare data-category and expect it to work the same, but it doesn't.

```
$(function() {
    $('#select-item').on('change', function() {
        var itemValue= this.value;
        console.log(itemValue); //text is logged e.g. item2
        $('#select-secondItem option').hide().filter(function() {
            return this.value.indexOf(itemValue) === 0;
        })
        .show();
    })
    .change();
});
```

I've tried modifying it like this

```
$(function() {
    $('#select-item').on('change', function() {
        var  itemValue=$(this).data("category");
        console.log(itemValue); //undefined is logged
        $('#select-secondItem option').hide().filter(function() {
            return $(this).data("category") === itemValue;
        })
        .show();
    })
    .change();
});
```

No error is displayed in the console, but it doesn't work as the above one

Comment: `$(this).data("category")` should be `$(this).find("option:selected").data("category")`

Comment: @Swati in both `itemValue` and `return`?

Comment: In itemValue you need to change .

Comment: You can't hide options cross browser. Some don't support it. Choices are enable/disable or remove/replace

Comment: @Swati this seems to have done it, thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know how to reset options choice in the `#select-secondItem` list each time I change the option in the `#select-item`?

Comment: @Fico again, should really be a new question :) (but then it would be closed as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31536647/2181514)) I'm also not sure if there's a limit on questions in a time frame.   To clear a `select` use `$("#select-secondItem").val("")`